# Updating dhtmlx-sheduler uisng React

Tags: reactjs, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using scheduler as follows:

From a dropdown(react-select), I choose a name (whose events I have to show on the scheduler) and it shows correctly,

nextState.showData is an array of data.

```
window.scheduler.parse(nextState.showData, 'json')
```

but when I deselect the same name, the scheduler should update and show me no events, but the scheduler does not update(and still shows the event for the name which is now deselected)

Although, on deselect of the name, `nextState.showData=[]`.

Please help. I am using dhtmlx-scheduler with React........

Answer (score 0):

This is how, I solved the problem

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.showData.length===0) {
        window.scheduler.clearAll();
        window.scheduler.parse([], 'json')
    }
    else {
        window.scheduler.clearAll();
        window.scheduler.parse(this.props.showData, 'json')
    }
}
```

Rather than parsing the data in `shouldComponentUpdate()`, I did in `componentDidUpdate()` and it solved my problem

Courtesy
https://forum.dhtmlx.com/t/gantt-not-re-rendering-after-update/37702/2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the main idea is that you should call `scheduler.clearAll()` each time before you `parse()` new data set.

You can remove `window.scheduler.parse([], 'json')` in the `if` condition because this line does nothing in the code.

It makes sense to change your code in the next way:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    window.scheduler.clearAll();
    if(this.props.showData.length) {
        window.scheduler.parse(this.props.showData, 'json')
    }
}
```